# MessageBox() not responsing in WM_ACTIVATEAPP on touchscreen

Tags: c++, c, winapi, touchscreen, win32gui

I notice that MessageBox routine (or any modal dialog) is not responsing (hanging) in **WM_ACTIVATEAPP** message processing while activating an app via touchscreen, whereas activating an app via mouse works fine.

```
case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
    MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Not responsing with touchscreen"), TEXT("Help!"), MB_OK);
break;
```

The message box is showing without responsing of mouse-click or finger-touch and the whole application is freezing - I have to kill app by using task manager.

Is it a knowing bug of Win32 API? Is there any work around for this problem?

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  How did you determine the hang is in the WM_ACTIVATEAPP message processing?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Windows 7's touch input support is pretty broken. It has been reworked starting with Windows 8.

Comment: A snippet of code might help

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: By hanging I mean the dialog don't answer mouse click and my whole application freeze completely - I have to kill it with the task manager.

Comment: @IInspectable : I reproduce it under my Windows 10. But some users reproduce it under Windows 8

Comment: @Phixle: Thank you for your suggestion. Code snippet has been added.

Comment: @HansPassant: The message box is showing but it just doesn't answer the mouse-click/finger-touch, because whole application freezes. However no freeze if I use mouse to activate my app.

Answer (score 2):

WM_ACTIVATEAPP is a "difficult" message, your app is in an awkward state with your window in the process of getting activated and getting the focus but it did not yet get there by the time you get the message.  You never want to do anything to block the message handler and write code that requires the active window to be known or change the active window.  Like MessageBox() does.  A deadlock is not unusual, especially so in a 32-bit app that runs in the Wow64 emulator.

Don't block, simply delay the displaying of the message box:

```
case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_USER, NULL, NULL);
    DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    break;
case WM_USER:
    MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Responsing with touchscreen"), TEXT("Okay!"), MB_OK); 
    break;
```

Whether the DefWindowProc() call is necessary is a guess, you didn't post enough code.

Comment: Thank you very much @Hans Passant for this very pertinent answer!
Not only your solution solve the hanging problem, but also it makes my code more elegant!